# Selecting the correct Gaussian process prior for a regression function

Tags: model-selection, aic, gaussian-process

Let
$$ y_i = f(x_i) + \varepsilon_i \quad i=1,\ldots,n $$
where the $\varepsilon_i$ are iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Consider the Gaussian process priors $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$:
$$ \pi_1: f \sim GP(0,\lambda A) $$
$$ \pi_2: f \sim GP(0,\mu B) $$
for covariance kernels $A$ and $B$, and smoothing parameters $\lambda>0$ and $\mu>0$.

We assume $f$ was generated by either $\pi_1$ or $\pi_2$, but we do not know which. The objective is to find which prior is correct. We may consider the marginal likelihoods $L_1(\lambda,\sigma^2|y)$ and $L_2(\mu,\sigma^2|y)$ based on $\pi_1$ resp. $\pi_2$, maximize these, and select the prior yielding the highest maximized marginal likelihood. As both likelihoods have the same number of parameters, this is the same as choosing based on AIC or BIC.

Are there any conditions under which this procedure will select the correct prior with probability going to 1 as $n\to\infty$? My worry is that it may happen that the maximum likelihood estimators $\hat\lambda\to 0$ and $\hat\mu\to 0$, as $n\to\infty$, so there isn't consistency in the usual sense, which is a prerequisite for AIC and BIC I think.